# Property 'package_number_7' not found on object of type 'User *' after Lightweight Migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, xcode6

I have a CoreData based application.
In my data model I've changed data model just by add to User entity row "package_number_7" and use Lightwight Migration (just adjust appdelegate) .. Now when I want to use this "package_number_7" in fetch request it's not working.
here is sample code from viewcontroller

```
- (BOOL)paidPackage:(int)package_id
{

    int result = 0;
    CoreDataStack *dataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:dataStack.managedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [dataStack.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    for (User *s in fetchedObjects) {

        switch (package_id)
        {
            case 1:
                result = [s.paid_package_1 boolValue]; // Balicek 1
                break;
            case 2:
                result = [s.paid_package_2 boolValue]; // Balicek 2
                break;
            case 3:
                result = [s.paid_package_3 boolValue]; // Balicek 3
                break;
            case 4:
                result = [s.paid_package_4 boolValue]; // Balicek 4
                break;
            case 5:
                result = [s.paid_package_5 boolValue]; // Balicek 5
                break;
            case 6:
                result = [s.paid_package_6 boolValue]; // Balicek 6
                break;
            case 7:
                result = [s.paid_package_7 boolValue]; // Balicek 7
                break;
            case 8:
                //result = [s.paid_package_8 boolValue]; // Balicek 8
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

**error at package_number_7 is -> Property 'package_number_7' not found on object of type 'User *'**

I have tried clean application, and rebuild again.

Comment: Please share User class .h/.m file

Comment: Oh man ! many thanks, I forgot for classes ! thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your user class header file , if you miss "package_number_7" to declare.